# Creating a UK map with geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

I am quite new to R and have recently been trying to create an outline of the UK in ggplot2 with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
UK <- map_data("world2Hires", region = "UK")
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
coord_map()
```

Result of ggplot2 code:

[image: Result of ggplot2 code]

This creates the map above as it does not take into account the longitude scale of the map and stretches it across the x-axis. The UK has a longitude that spans from -x to +x which is causing the problem here. I have not been able to find any way of fixing this so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not bound to `world2Hires`, you can do the following, which gives me the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
UK <- map_data(map = "world", region = "UK") # changed map to "world"
ggplot(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  coord_map()
```

[image: UK Map]

Does that help you?

Comment: That is great, thank you for that. Just what I need as I only knew about world2Hires. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! What you should try is consulting the help, i.e., type `?map_data`, or `?geom_map` to see example code!