# Plotting nb object in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, spatial

I would like to plot the outline of UK, along with an nb object that I generated from a spatial points dataframe.

The problem is that the outline of UK takes really, really long to plot --it keeps crashing my Rstudio. This for example, either take really long to load or my Rstudio just stops responding.

```
library(raster)    
UK_gadm <- getData("GADM", country="GB", level=0)
    plot(UK_gadm)
```

So I resorted to using ggplot2 from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673461/creating-a-uk-map-with-geom-polygon) where I can get the outline of UK like in a fraction of a second with the following commands:

```
library(ggplot2)
UK <- map_data(map = "world", region = "UK") # changed map to "world"
    ggplot(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
      geom_polygon() +
      coord_map()
```

The issue now is that I would like the nb object to be plotting against the backdrop of the outline of UK -- however, this seems only achievable in base R like [for example](http://geog.uoregon.edu/GeogR/topics/spneighbors.html):

```
plot(orotl.shp, xlim=c(-125, -115), ylim=c(42,47))
plot(orstationc.neighbors.dist, orstationc.loc, add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
```

Is there any way I could plot nb objects in ggplot or is there a way for R to plot the outline of UK without crashing my computer with the base R plot function?

Comment: What is an nb object? Also, can you provide a minimum usable data set ? For instance, what is in orotl.shp and orstationc.neighbors.dist?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a fast, simple solution after a whole night of effort. Hope this helps someone else with a similar issue.

Just to elaborate on the goal: plot a neighbours object (nb) against a shapefile. This is to visualise the linkages among certain coordinates. After some googling, I think this can only be done with base R's plot function.  The problem however, was loading a country's shapefile (downloaded from official sources/gadm)-- its too big.

To solve this issue, get a more generalised, simple map of the country via the maps package, turn it into a shapefile and then plot it alongside the neighbours object.

Here's the code:

```
library(spdep)

# get your neighbour object from your spatial points df
rest_neighbours <- dnearneigh(rest_spdf,0,1)

library(maps)

# get boundary of UK
UK_map <- sf::st_as_sf(maps::map(database='world',regions='UK', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

# write to shapefile
st_write(UK_map, 'shapefiles/UK.shp')

# henceforth, we can just call the shapefile 
UK <- readOGR('shapefiles/UK.shp')

# plot the boundary and the neighbours
plot(UK)
plot(rest_neighbours, rest_coords, add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
```

I did not realise that official boundary files are often really detailed which also means that they are really huge and I'm glad that there's ready-made watered down versions of the maps available in the maps package of r. (Sorry if you already knew -- I'm still learning!)

Hope this helps anyone else!

Answer (score 1):

```
  library(spdep)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(sf)
  
  #Here one example
  ColData1 <- sf::st_read(system.file("shapes/columbus.shp", package="spData")[1], quiet=TRUE)
  coords1 = sf::st_coordinates(sf::st_centroid(ColData1)) # coordinates of the census tract centroids
  IDs1 = row.names(ColData1)
  ColData1$IDs1 = IDs1
  col_nb1 = poly2nb(ColData1, queen = TRUE)
  summary(col_nb1)
  class(col_nb1) # check the class of col_nb

  # convert nb to sf with binary weights
  col_nb1_sf = spdep::nb2lines(col_nb1, coords=coords1, proj4string=NULL, as_sf=T) # weights are binary
  

  
  # plot
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data=ColData1, fill=NA, color="red", lwd=0.5) +
    geom_sf(data=sf::st_centroid(ColData1), pch=19, color="blue") +
    geom_sf(data=col_nb1_sf, color="blue", lwd=0.3, lty=2) +
    geom_sf_label(data=ColData1, aes(label=IDs1), size = 2) +
    #geom_sf_text(data=ColData1, aes(label=IDs1), size = 3) +
    labs(title="Adjacency Connection", subtitle = "Columbus Shapefile") + 
    xlab("") +
    ylab("")
```

Comment: This code uses `ggplot` as the question requirement